# "an error occurred trying to start process" (im trying to launch subnautica as a test for my other program)

Tags: c#

```
private static void DataReceived(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    UdpClient c = (UdpClient)ar.AsyncState;
    IPEndPoint receivedIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
    Byte[] receivedBytes = c.EndReceive(ar, ref receivedIpEndPoint);


    string receivedText = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedBytes);
    Console.Write(receivedIpEndPoint + ": " + receivedText + Environment.NewLine);

    c.BeginReceive(DataReceived, ar.AsyncState);
    var p = new Process
    {
        StartInfo =
            {
                FileName = @"C:\Users\Andrei\Desktop\Subnautica.v63668\Subnautica.exe",
                Arguments = "127.0.0.1 20000",
                UseShellExecute = true
            }
    };



    p.Start();
}
```

}

"an error occurred trying to start process" (im trying to launch subnautica as a test for my other program)

Comment: Can you add what steps you've tried to solving this yourself? This will help to provide a baseline for us to know how to help you

Comment: Please provide some examples you've already tried or at least give some more detailed informations about your code / problem.